# Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol

Tags: c++, opengl, visual-studio-2012, linker, glew

*I have seen many topics on this but it did not help me.

I am getting errors from the code:

[image]

I have seen many topics on this and I did everything on the answers. 
Here is my includes:

```
#ifndef _OPENGL_INCLUDES
#define _OPENGL_INCLUDES

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>


#pragma comment(lib, "opengl32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glu32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "glew32.lib")
#endif
```

On Linker -> Input I have glew32.lib
[image]

In addition I put the glew32.lib file in:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib and C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\Release\x64

I have glew32.dll on System32 so why am I keep getting this error? What have I missed?

Comment: _"I have seen many topics on this and I did everything on the answers"_ You didn't!

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit -  So can you please tell me what I did not do?

Comment: I don't know; haven't spent time examining it. Read the research material again! We spent lots of time compiling it for you to read yourself, so that we wouldn't have to keep doing so over and over again.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit - I am searching for 3 hours and still can figure it out, I will be glad if you help me.

Comment: Three hours isn't a very long time. How did you try "everything on the answers" in just three hours? You should get used to it now: spending _days_ researching your problems. It's a critical skill, as is patience! Good luck.

Comment: Lightness Races in Orbit - I followed this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u_NI7KOzyFM I did EVERYTHING and it still does not work. I guess it is something else that blocks the link. Can I please get some help?

Comment: Yeah, you can read the huge amount of information on the topic in the linked question. That's right, not watching a video: _READING_. This is not a helpdesk mate you have to do your own debugging and we have spent a lot of time providing you, for free, with all the research material you need to fix your problem. Now it's your responsibility to make use of it.